# Monocot stele in roots

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

Why do monocots have eustele in the roots instead of protostele like dicots? I thought the roots don't need the strength of eustele because the roots are supported by the soil. So what is the evolutionary reason for the eustele in the roots of monocots?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a trait would be advantageous to an organism, why hasn't it evolved?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/if-a-trait-would-be-advantageous-to-an-organism-why-hasnt-it-evolved)