# Are there any biological obstacles prohibiting lighter-than-air organisms?

Tags: evolution

Why there are no organisms that use cavities filled with lighter-than air substances (e.g. hydrogen) to fly and remain in air?

Given that there are a lot of fish and algae that use similar cavities to float, it is surprising that no organism utilized the same mechanism to fly.

Comment: I don't know of any organism that uses cavities soley to fly; birds have air sacs to help them fly, and very light bones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_sacs

Comment: @Ro Siv what's the purpose of air sacs filled with normal air? It only worsens aerodynamics.

Comment: This tends to be a question like [***If a trait would be advantageous to an organism, why hasn't it evolved?***](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35532/3340)

Comment: Because organisms would need to develop an electrolysis system or a steam refractory apparatus. Rather energy consuming. Better to flap some wings I reckon.