# Why would a python go after such large prey?

Tags: ethology, herpetology, antipredator-adaptation, snake

I read that most Pythons would go for smaller prey, around the size of a house cat, but that larger species enjoy crocodiles, deer and even a bit of antelope for dinner. But why?

Now, I realise that evolution is ongoing, and that [even in the year infinity evolution can't be expected to result in any subjective measure of "perfection"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35532/10062). But, even so, it seems odd to me that this behaviour could have survived the eons.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the animal's physiology and it's more mobile in this state than I expect, but isn't this animal utterly defenceless for the next couple of weeks while it digests its tasty snack? Couldn't something else now come along, rip open the snake, steal its crocodile then leave the snake for dead, all without encountering much in the way of effective resistance?

One possible answer I thought of was that other animals may not much like the taste of half-digested crocodile. Conceivably, one could stalk the snake waiting for it to start swallowing the croc, then grab it while the food is still relatively fresh. But I doubt any animal that's not already substantially stronger than the snake would feel too comfortable stalking it in the first place. Is that enough to explain why Pythons have gotten into the habit of apparently making themselves sitting ducks for protracted periods of time rather than simply eating less more often?

Comment: I dunno, maybe it _is_ a behaviour liable to be selected out, but it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Also I may have overestimated the digestion period ([_"Witnesses said it took this snake about five hours to swallow the crocodile. During that time the snake is vulnerable to attack from a dingo."_](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-26417534)) based on something I read elsewhere. Anyway, looking forward to your expert thoughtz.

Comment: @DonJulian: Not really the sort of deep thought I'm looking for in an answer...