# Is there an evolutionary advantage associated with migraine?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution, neuroscience, pain

I have read [Wikipedia article on Genetics of migraine headaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetics_of_migraine_headaches) and I don't buy it

> Because genetics influence susceptibility to migraine, it can be
>   shaped by evolution. Fitness-impairing disorders, including severe
>   headache, tend to disappear as a result of natural selection, and
>   their frequency decreases to near the rate of spontaneous
>   mutation. However, migraine has not
>   diminished over millions of years of evolution. Its prevalence has at
>   least been maintained at a high level, and has even been shown to be
>   increasing.
>   This phenomenon suggests that a central nervous system (CNS)
>   susceptible to severe, intermittent headache has been linked to an
>   important survival or reproductive advantage.

the argument in wiki is equivalent to **since we know that evolution is correct - it means that headaches must benefit us somehow otherwise we wouldn't have it** so let's think of some reasons - which is in my opinion is a fallacy.

I could believe that this is a bad side effect of some more efficient to survival trait like being smart, ([which is partially covered in same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetics_of_migraine_headaches#Headache_as_a_design_construct))

> Finally, migraine may be a component of imperfect central nervous
>   system design. Evidence has suggested a dysfunction of pain-inhibitory
>   pathways in migraine and discordant interaction between the ancient
>   brain stem design and the more evolved neocortex.

**EDIT:**

I have read the [meta post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/questions-asking-for-evolutionary-reasons) and [answer from WYSIWYG](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont), and I agree that they do partially answer my question in regard that a mild 'badness' can get past. I would argue that my question is different in a way that I am referring to specific point `The trait might have a tradeoff which essentially makes no change to the overall fitness` 
The way I understand it is that one gets some 'perk' that is beneficial in some situations and disadvantageous in others and they cancel each-other out. (I just don't see how without some huge benefit migraines would get past). What I am asking is what so advantageous we must have gotten - that such horrible thing like migraines got through.

**Are there any studies done - that incapacitating migraines are coupled with an evolutionary trait?**

Comment: There is no need for a benefit from a trait to stay - it is necessary that it is not selected against this trait.

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris, I see what you are saying, don't you find it hard to believe that incapacitating migraines would not get selected against? I can't think where whey would not reduce performance be it mental or physical.

Comment: We don't know the exact genetic basis for migraine as far as I know (might be wrong). Unless we do, we cannot decide, if migraine is the backside for some other, much more beneficial trait also connected with these genes or gene variants. The classic example for this is sickle cell anemia - not beneficial unless you live in an area where malaria is endemic.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris, there is this article on twins with migranes, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2779399/pdf/10194_2007_Article_427.pdf  `At present,
several loci 4q21-q24, 5q21, 6p12.2-p21.1, 11q24,
14q21.2-q22.3 and 15q11-q13 linked to common forms of
migraine with evidence of linkage have been reported.`

Comment: See [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35532/3340).

Comment: @WYSIWYG Hi WYSIWYG, I have read the meta post and answer you have linked, and I agree that they do partially answer my question in regart that a mild 'badness' can get past. I would argue that my question is different as it is referring to specific point in your answer, `The trait might have a tradeoff which essentially makes no change to the overall fitness.`. What I am asking is with which trait did we get migraines (that was so great that even such incapacitating thing like migrenes got past). If you think I should change the wording, please just say so. Thanks.

Comment: @WYSIWYG edited the question.

Comment: I've updated my [answer here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont/35658#35658) - it should answer your question -  see the last bullet point in particular

Comment: I have altered your title, correcting the grammar and phrasing it in a scientific manner.

Comment: smart apes stayed on the cave with his migraine, while the dumb ones were killed hunting, and that's why we have migraine today.

Comment: @montelof and he died from starvation....

Comment: no, in that case migraine would not exists, he probably discovered agriculture.