# Would someone lose some of their traits if they stop using them for some time?

Tags: evolution

A co-worker of mine told me, that there are some mutations in the genome during the life of a human body. So, the body changes genes to fit better into the surrounding environment.

My thought is now, if it is true, every generation of human beings loses some abilities which the body has not needed till the time.

A hypothetical example: in a time where education takes even more time and importance than now, would human beings lose their mechanical skills because they do little physical work?

Comment: You seem to have several major misconceptions about evolution and mutations. I strongly suggest reading through [Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) from the University of California, Berkeley.

Comment: @MattDMo: this is ablolut true, thats why I'm asking.

Comment: This question is relatively clear and easy to answer. I disagree with the close votes and with the down votes.

Comment: It has been substantially edited since I voted to close, retracted vote now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A co-worker of mine told me, that there are some mutations in the genome during the life of a human body. So, the body changes genes to fit better into the surrounding environment.

Yes mutations accumulate during the lifetime but they are random. They are not targeted in a way that the organism adapts to the environment. Evolution happens through multiple generations and not in a single lifetime.

> ... every generation of human beings loses some abilities which the body has not needed till the time.

No. That does not happen.

It was once actually hypothesized by Lamarck that an organism gains or loses traits based on the use and disuse of those traits, respectively.

We now know that it is not true. A trait is not removed from the population unless it imposes a strong survival disadvantage to the population.

For more details see [Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35532/3340)