# Why were wisdom teeth not eliminated by evolution?

Tags: evolution

Supposedly evolution was very efficient and evolved many human proteins over a few thousand generations. Yet obvious detrimental traits like wisdom teeth remained. Why?

Comment: You're asking about one specific case, but I think the more [general question here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont) has good answers for you.

Comment: Not everyone has problems with impacted wisdom teeth, and removing them is a profitable enterprise, so please use caution before you say we should evolve to 'x'. We have always had wisdom teeth, but removing them is a relatively recent affair.

Comment: Please explain why wisdom teeth are "obviously" detrimental, because it's certainly not obvious to me :-)

Comment: I dunno who would describe evolution as "very efficient", it can result in amazing solutions that would be incredibly hard to arrive at by design but making random changes and throwing away the bad ones is not exactly quick or waste-free.

Comment: I would also point out that evolution does not have a will! It just happens. The fact that some traits change faster or slower over time is a matter of chance.

Comment: I am changing the title by removing "yet it evolved several proteins". "Evolution evolved" is like saying "change changed" — redundant. And the idea that only *several* proteins evolved is quite wrong. All proteins evolved.

Comment: @Liu Considering the answer to the question this is supposed to be a duplicate of gives a long lost many possible factors, you could make this a valid question just by asking which point or points on the list are responsible in this case. including the list or a link to it would a good idea if you do this.

Comment: In addition to other points, Google says that wisdom teeth usually come in in the late teens or early 20s.  In prior ages, many people would have had at least one offspring by then, perhaps more, reducing the space for evolution to act against any detrimental effect.

Answer (score 1):

Reductions in the size of our lower jaw that result in wisdom teeth sometimes becoming impacted result from changes in our diet, and are not the direct result of the evolution of a smaller jaw. This means that natural selection has had at most 8000 years to act on the phenomenon, which occurs in people in their mid to late 20s (who, historically, probably would have already reproduced if they were going to), and so the selective advantage of lacking wisdom teeth has not had enough time or been strong enough to cause the no-wisdom-teeth phenotype to spread throughout the human population.

[Global human mandibular variation reflects differences in agricultural and hunter-gatherer subsistence strategies - Cramon-Taubadel, PNAS (2011)](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/49/19546.abstract)

[Before Agriculture, Human Jaws Were a Perfect Fit for Human Teeth - Smithsonian.com (2015)](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/how-dawn-farming-changed-our-mouths-worst-180954167/)

[Incongruity between Affinity Patterns Based on Mandibular and Lower Dental Dimensions following the Transition to Agriculture in the Near East, Anatolia and Europe - PLOS One (2015)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0117301)

Comment: the real risk with wisdom teeth is splitting the jaw, but as you said that only became a problem after the invention of soft processed food.

Comment: I would wager that removal of impacted wisdom teeth has resulted in more deaths than infection from said teeth. **There is not a single randomized trial** proving - or even attempting to prove - that removal of wisdom teeth has a beneficial effect on quality/duration of life. The UK's NHS stopped paying for the standard procedure, and the Cochrane Report advises against it. I have my wisdom teeth; my dentist was peeved because one of them had a small cavity. When I asked why he was upset, he answered that they were hard to fill way back there. He advised me to have it removed. Um, nope.

Comment: Furthermore, neither of your your citations (one depends on the other) does not deal with wisdom teeth, but with malocclusion. You need better sources. -1 for misinterpretation/misinterpretation of support sources.

Comment: @John - Whaaaaaat???

Comment: @anongoodnurse It's possible that wisdom teeth cause problems and also removing wisdom teeth causes problems. I wasn't arguing in favour of surgery, or against it, modern surgery is irrelevant to the discussion.

The PLOS One paper discusses jaw size changes as a result of change in lifestyle, I've found another paper that discusses it more explicitly. I've made the assumption that this would be the cause dental crowding and impaction of wisdom teeth problems, I suppose this assumption could be wrong.

Comment: Your assumption ignores the much more common malocclusions which create "problems". Modern surgery is not irrelevant to the discussion. **The death rate from impacted wisdom teeth is not known** (contrary to your statement that infections from impaction kill), nor has it ever been known. In other words, the "problem" of wisdom teeth is largely a recently manufactured problem. Malocclusion is not. Yet we have lived with it for 10 millenia or more.

Comment: It seems a fairly safe bet that before antibiotics all infections carried a risk of serious repercussions, but I don't actually know that, so fair enough.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, problem=/= death. The fact that our change in diet is responsible for smaller jaws in industrial societies and this is responsible for the majority the problems associated with wisdom teeth is what matters for question. The cost/benefit of surgery was not mentioned becasue it is irrelevant.

Comment: @John - I'm not sure what you're talking about. My comment to you was about wisdom teeth splitting jaws. In almost 40 years of treating patients, I have never heard that one! If you could cite a source, I need to read it, please. Otherwise I will continue to believe it's a whopper, that one; it is indeed! We're *scientists* here.

Comment: @anongoodnurse http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1079210405802999 You should not rely on anacdotal evidence, esspecially when refering to something that became a problem prior to the development of modern medical technology. And I was referring to several of your above post, I would not normally rely to "Whaaat?" or anything like it.

Comment: @John - Thanks for the link. Please note that there is no control group; everyone in that study had a fractured mandible. What percent of people with M3s have mandibular fractures? Is it significant? And, please note: people make a great deal of money by pushing for the removal of M3s. Whenever someone who does this for a living publishes a study which supposes to support it, you *should* always ask, is there a conflict of interest? In other words, *quis bono*? Too many third parties have found differently. Again, *quis bono*?

Comment: control groups for injury causes tend to be prohibitively expensive to create becasue you must have a much much larger sample size usually combined with an extremely long study length, it doesn't bother me in the slightest they don't have one.  We already know wisdom teeth are more likely to develop impaction, the cost/benefit of surgery is largely individualistic and irrelevant to the discussion. If you have links to any of these third party studies showing no connection that would be helpful to your case.

Comment: It is not irrelevant that the researchers have a vested interest in promoting the agenda that impacted wisdom teeth should be removed.

Comment: @John: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD003879.pub2/full "There is some reliable evidence that suggests that the prophylactic removal of asymptomatic impacted wisdom teeth in adolescents neither reduces nor prevents late incisor crowding."

Comment: @anongoodnurse you do realize that does not show no connection,  just no connection between a very narrow subset of wisdom teeth and another narrow set of complications. If you want to continue this I suggest creating a chat.

Answer (score 0):

Wisdom teeth do have a function. If you are missing a molar before the age of 20, a wisdom tooth can easily move in to fill in the gap, by filling in the space or by pushing the molar ahead of it.

This trick has been used by dentist to "fix" the teeth of teenagers who have  molars with large cavities but still have wisdom teeth that have not erupted. So rather than go to extremes to save a bad molar, it is just yanked out and the wisdom tooth slips in. Problem solve. ( of course it depend on the actual wisdom tooth as some wisdom teeth are improperly positioned or appears unlikely to erupt to enable this  trick to be used) [example](https://www.orthodontisteenligne.com/en/dentition-en/wisdom-teeth-myths-and-realities/)

Modern dental hygiene is good (but not good enough). So people tend to have all their molars in their early 20s (but not in their mid 30s). The the wisdom comes in too early to be useful to modern people. But i am guessing it had more use in earlier times.

That said... the trait for (third molars) wisdom teeth does not appear to be under positive selection in the human population as not everyone has it. Numbers vary depending on population.  10 to 25 percent of Americans of European ancestry are missing at least one third molar. For African Americans it is 11% and Asian Americans, the figure is 40 percent. The Inuit, a group of people who live in the Arctic regions of Canada, Greenland and Alaska, have the fewest wisdom teeth; about 45 percent of them lack one or more third molar.

[percentage](http://www.livescience.com/27529-missing-wisdom-teeth.html)

Comment: You need a source for your statement that wisdom teeth are being selected against. That is not a credible claim.