# Nature of transmarginal inhibition

Tags: evolution, neuroscience

I've recently become aware about existence of such phenomena. From my naive point of view, I understood it as existence of two general types of neural cells, one type serve inhibitory purpose and the other one provide excitation, all of this happens through variation of concentration of different mediators in synaptic connections, right? So in this process (transmarginal inhibition), in a nutshell, provoked by overwhelming stimuli, layer of cells which inhibit inhibitory cell start to show increase of activity and hence inhibitory cells can no longer control activity of currently "excited" cells which result in "paradoxal", reversed behavior. Sorry for this clumsy explanation of how I understood this, please correct my view. If i can abstractly think about evolution of some particular part of biological system as a function which tries to arrive at "local maximum", what type of arrangement of environmental variables could introduce this kind of structure which suffer from such horrible drawback. I mean, there was some input and desired output (adaptation), in result we got construction which could be shut down be intensive external influence and permanently corrupted.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the logic of your explanation, can you rewrite, or cite a source? It doesn't look like transmarginal inhibition specifically is a common area of study in neuroscience today, it's an old term from Pavlov. And I'm wondering why you think this is adaptive - most of the references to it are talking about conditions like schizophrenia or post-traumatic stress. Just because a phenomenon is observed in nature doesn't mean it helps survival.

Comment: Hello Bryan,  thank you for response, i have a pleasure to attend a lecture related to brain structure in local university, and professor accidentally mention Pavlov and this subject in particular, i reproduce as i remember his explanation. I probably poorly state final part of question, will edit it right now.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced that this is a bad trait, because sometimes lack of response can be adaptive (e.g. "playing dead" can be an adaptive response). However, see [this question and the answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont).