# Why isn’t prokaryotic mRNA modified post-transcriptionally like eukaryotic mRNA?

Tags: transcription

Eukaryotic mRNA is subject to addition of a methyl-guanosine cap at the 5’ end, addition of 100-200 adenosines to the 3’ end, and splicing. Why don’t these occur in prokaryotes? Is it because there is no exonuclease and intron in prokaryotes?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Before posting a question it is important to make sure it is scientifically correct and clear. Your title referred to post-translational modification and there was no mention that you are talking about mRNA. Having corrected that, we see that 1. you are asking about three distinct post-transcriptional processes, 2. It is not clear what you mean by "why" — do you want to know the function of each (which are described in any text) or some basic reason why mRNA (and its translation) has evolved differently in eukaryotes or prokaryotes? The latter can only be speculated on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont)