# Is the human mouth more burn-resistant than other animals which don't eat cooked food?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-evolution

I burnt my mouth on some hot pizza and it got me wondering if we have been eating cooked food long enough to have evolved a better resistance to oral burns than other species. Have there been any studies on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35532/27148 - to evolve a trait by selection it has to have some fitness benefit. For humans to evolve protection against pizza burns it would have to afford a survival/reproductive benefit, not just be a "nice to have".

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site (also see: ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)). Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont)