# Why DNA polymerases don't have helicase activity

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

RNA polymerases have intrinsic helicase ability, while DNA polymerases don't.
I am curious why DNA polymerases evolved in such a way that they lack the ability to unwind DNA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont)

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the time to  finish reading the [Tour] and read the Help section on [Asking Good Questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Two things we require  of posters is clarity and evidence of previous research on the subject. You do not make it clear whether you are aware that there is a separate helicase involved in DNA replication and, if you are, whether you have thought about the differences between DNA-dependant DNA and RNA synthesis. Furthermore, evolution can lead to different solutions to the same problem, when asking why is fruitless.

Comment: @tyersome — I don't see how the referenced question is relevant to this one. We are not dealing with bad traits, but different methods of dividing labour in relation to highly evolved fundamental systems of nucleic acid synthesis.