# Why do cells use microRNA to break down mRNA, instead of not transcribing it in the first place?

Tags: gene-expression, mrna, microrna

As I understand it, microRNAs are used to ensure that certain genes are only expressed when needed. The way this apparently works is that when the translation products of an mRNA are not required the appropriate microRNA is transcribed to bind to the mRNA and initiate its nucleolytic degradation.

My question is if the cell can detect that the product of a specific mRNA is not required why is the mRNA transcribed it all, rather than synthesizing it and then synthesizing another RNA to silence it?

Comment: Hi Sam. I rolled back your recent edit, but I understand your frustration. Yours is an interesting question, though, as it stands, it is practically impossible to answer. If you reduce the scope of your question, you may find someone willing to take a crack at it. For instance, instead of asking why microRNAs exist (redundancy?), perhaps you can ask whether microRNA regulation is energetically beneficial from the cellular perspective, relative to control at the levels of transcription (TF abundance and binding) or translation.

Comment: @acvill: I disagree. It is not impossible to answer. miRNAs allow a cell to rapidly remove any present mRNA in order to react quickly. Furthermore, every mRNA is subject to constant production/degradation (RNA Homeostasis, [Pelkmans 2022](https://www.cell.com/trends/cell-biology/fulltext/S0962-8924(22)00120-9?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0962892422001209%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)). This question is about RNA biochemistry. [This](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont) does not contain an answer.

Comment: @markur your comment addresses *how* miRNAs help maintain mRNA homeostasis. The question asks *why* miRNAs evolved as a control mechanism. We can speculate, but, generally, it’s very difficult to know why a particular trait or pathway evolved alongside / in lieu of another.

Comment: @markur if you believe the question should be reopened, feel free to submit an edit.

Comment: @acvill ok cool, I submitted an edit, let me know if I did something wrong. And sure, I get why one might consider this question is related to "traits". However, I feel it's unfair to depict this question as speculative, considered that there is just so much knowledge about how and why RNAs are produced and regulated and degraded etc.

Comment: @acvill — I disagree. The question is from a naive user ("I am learning" or something of the sort) who seems not to realize that if you light a candle and finish the game you may want to snuff the candle out as well as not lighting another. Of course the question of why one mechanism rather than another for a specific gene is speculative and has to be considered on a case by case basis, but I think that can be mentioned, with examples of other regulatory mechanisms. There is also the point of circuits and oscillations with multiple regulatory controls (that I do not understand). Try my edit.

Comment: @David that's a good edit. I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer**

Switch On: To **start** expressing a protein-coding gene — synthesizing its product — you have at some stage to synthesize its mRNA — transcribe it.

Switch Off: To **stop** expressing a protein-coding gene it makes sense to stop making more RNA, as the poster suggests. *But that may not be enough*! Many eukaryotic mRNAs have half-lives ranging from hours to days, so that merely stopping transcription will not immediately stop the protein being produced. If it is important to stop synthesis immediately, something else is required. Nucleolytic degradation of the mRNA initiated by microRNAs is one way to do this.

**More than one way to kill a cat**

Why is this not more widespread? The answer is that this is only one of a variety of means to regulate gene expression. Others include having mRNAs of shorter half-life (as in bacteria), controlling mRNA translation, inactivation of the protein (if it is an enzyme) or degrading the product by proteolysis. Which method is employed depends on evolutionary chance, the nature of the system, whether it is advantageous to be able to resume activity quickly etc. So systems regulated by microRNA need to be considered on a case-by-case basis.

And although I am not competent to write on this (additions solicited) I am led to believe that mathematical modelling shows that the existence of a variety of regulatory mechanisms can allow a smoother and more buffered response to a variety of stimuli.

Answer (score 1):

The key differences are:

- miRNA act very **quickly** (hours, day). Transcriptional repression stops production, but doesn‘t remove the gene‘s signal since the mRNA is still there.
- one miRNA can target **multiple (even *hundreds* of) different transcripts**  coming from different genomic loci, causing significant changes to the transcriptome at once. That‘s needed for differentiation processes (see *let-7*: [Balzeau 2017](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2017.00031/full)). Transcriptional repression can‘t handle that, since that would impose more extensive requirements on promoters/enhancers. ([Ni & Leng 2015](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405580815001168))
- miRNA evolved from an **anti-viral** system (RNA interference) that degrades viral dsRNA. Its machinery is multifunctional.
- miRNA can be transported between cells within extracellular vesicles. That way, **intercellular** communication causes quick changes to transcriptomes. Transcriptional repressors can‘t do that as easily, since they‘re localized to the nucleus and not the cytosol.