Reasons behind the sticky substances are used by poplar in buds
It is well known that sticky poplar buds falling on a car can seriously damage the paint. Also these scales from poplar stick to the paws and fur of animals like Velcro. Personally I don’t think the mentioned examples of sricky ‘cases’ explain the puprpose of the sticky buds. Indeed, what the reasons the sticky substances are used by poplar in buds.
I guess the bees could be a reason to collect the sticky substances. However, I can hardly see bees on poplars. Also, the sticky substances could prevent buds to be frozen in early spring (creating a time-delay in growth of buds). What is the right explanation?

See this question: "Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?" https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/
